# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' on python 3.8.0 mac OS 10.15.3

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Python 3.8.0 on Mac OS 10.15.3 (Catalina) with pyenv.

When I try to run a file, it returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've tried `brew install tcl-tk`. I'm a little worried that because I'm running python on top of pyenv, any third party tkinter module doesn't get run properly.

Running `brew doctor` returned:

```
Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  `/Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.8-config`
```

Comment: What do `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade python3` commands show?

Comment: Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  `/Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
  /Users/jm/.pyenv/shims/python3.8-config` and `brew upgrade python3` returned `Warning: python3 3.7.6_1 already installed`

Comment: Try removing the `python3.7` configs. See this [issue](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/python3-installation-with-tkinter/3636).

Comment: will it affect my pyenv setup though?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839

Answer (score 9):

After trying a bunch of things, this is how it finally worked:

```
$ brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use pip3 it's working in my pip3 install tk

Comment: When using Python there are a number of library management systems such as pip. My advice would be to only use one of them. I would also recommend Anaconda Navigator, which does all this stuff automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You should install `tkinter`. To install `tkinter` write this on console:

```
pip install tk
```

Comment: The `tk` package on PyPi has nothing to do with `tkinter`.