# Why can R plot out-of-the-box but Python (matplotlib) needs tkinter?

Tags: r, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I'm on a *nix server right now with limited install privileges and I'm appreciating a **distinct advantage of R over Python**: *you need fewer dependencies to plot in R*. I have X-forwarding set up and can plot away in R, but I can't with Python due to lack of a [backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python).

For Python, I've had to [install Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python) a few times - not a big deal - but now I'm in a situation where it's not obvious how to and I'm appreciating the ease of plotting with R. Wasn't Python supposed to be the "batteries included" language?

So how does R do it? Does *every* install of R come with Tkinter? Or is it using something else to create its plots?

Comment: Python includes tkinter in the windows distro but not in the others OS distro's. Like linux. Not sure about OSX but I think it is missing from OSX as well. That said no language can cover every need right out of the box.

Comment: @Mike. Wikipedia page says all three OS types have Tkinker in their Pythin distros.

Comment: @42 I have seen a lot of post about OSX and Linux missing tkinter. Here is one post stating it needs to be installed manually for OSX [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760908/7475225).

Comment: @42 that is just the 1st post that popped up when I googled it. I have seen several over the years with that same issue.

Comment: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Apple+Macintosh+and+Tcl%2FTk  I think that link is fairly conclusive evidence that Tcl is part of macOS. And there is reasonably firm evidence that Tkinker is part of binary distributions: https://www.python.org/about/apps/

Comment: You need to follow the `Tk` link to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Comment: This comes across as a rant about Python rather than an actual question. Certainly it isn't a Python question, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R ships a package named `tcltk` with all distributions.

```
packageDescription("tcltk")
#----output--------
Package: tcltk
Version: 3.6.1
Priority: base
Title: Tcl/Tk Interface
Author: R Core Team
Maintainer: R Core Team <R-core@r-project.org>
Description: Interface and language bindings to Tcl/Tk GUI elements.
License: Part of R 3.6.1
Imports: utils
NeedsCompilation: yes
Built: R 3.6.1; x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; 2019-07-26 13:35:28 UTC; unix

-- File: /usr/lib/R/library/tcltk/Meta/package.rds
```

You can tell it's going to be in every distribution from the line that says `Priority: base`. You can also find out more about optional graphics devices with:

```
 capabilities()
 #--- output -----

   jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp 
   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 
sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem 
   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
  cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

And a list of specific graphics device details can be found by following various links for the help page:

```
?Devices
```

Comment: Cool! Any chance you could use R's tcl/tk as a matplotlib backend?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can call R plot routines through the 'reticulate' python package but I don't know about matplotlib.

Comment: I do see 19 SO hits with a search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+reticulate+matplotlib