# Why pycharm keeps say No module named '_tkinter'??? I am new to python and pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I was trying to learn python on macbook pro, macos catalina v10.15.3
I was just trying to run:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
t.forward(100)
```

but pycharm gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/djtriestolearn/PycharmProjects/Tryturtle/001.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I tried my best already but still don't know what's wrong, somebody help please.

Comment: If the answer you posted was meant to be an edit to the question, please remove the answer and paste that code into your question: [Edit].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: "Python may not be configured for Tk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk)

Comment: You will have to install tkinter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not have tkinter installed, on MacOS this should be fixed by running

`brew install python --with-tcl-tk`

Reference: [Why my Python installed via home brew not include Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839/why-my-python-installed-via-home-brew-not-include-tkinter)

Comment: run in where? Like Terminal?? I am really new to this area, sorry.