# Macos python 3.9 idle IDLE can't import Tkinter

Tags: python, macos

On my Mac, I install python 3.9 via homebrew.
I try to launch idle and get this error:

```
> idle3

** IDLE can't import Tkinter.
Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **
```

MacOS: 11.4
Homebrew: 3.1.9-121-g654c78c
Python: 3.9.5

Comment: Try `brew install python-tk` as mentioned by an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919851/7857466)

Comment: It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Mac-only error, and as per @user3153765 's comment, running

```
brew install python-tk
```

will work as long as you have home-brew installed on your machine.  If you do not have home-brew, check it out [here](https://brew.sh)!  It is in my required reading list for all Mac-OS users.

If you decide, for some good reason that I have not thought of, not to use homebrew, you can also fix this with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

if you have chosen to go the Ubuntu-based package manager route

Answer (score 0):

Those who use MacPorts to manage their python modules can install tkinter with:

```
sudo port install py39-tkinter
```